# Recommended way to handle http errors inside my asp.net mvc 5 web application

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

i need a way to globally handle http errors inside my asp.net mvc web application. i did the following if the call to the action method is Ajax :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (xhr.status == 401)
            window.location = "/Account/Login";
        else if (xhr.status == 403 || xhr.status == 404)
            alert(xhr.statusText, 'Error');

        $(".loadingimage").hide();
    });
```

where my action method looks as follow:-

```
 [CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Edit", Model = "Skill")]
      public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteKBLink(int? skillid,int? linktokbid)
      {
          if (skillid == null || linktokbid==null)
          {
              return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
          }
      var linktokb=     await unitofwork.SkillRepository.FindLinkToKB(linktokbid.Value);
      if (linktokb == null)
              {
                  return new HttpStatusCodeResult(404, "The link has already been deleted.");
              }
```

but i am not sure how i can handle the http errors in-case the request is not ajax ? currently i will be redirected to http not found page .. thnaks

Answer (score 4):

This solution works well for me...

[1]: Remove all 'customErrors' & 'httpErrors' from Web.config

[2]: Check 'App_Start/FilterConfig.cs' looks like this:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

[3]: in 'Global.asax' add this method:

```
public void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Server.ClearError();

    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "ErrorPage");
    routeData.Values.Add("action", "Error");
    routeData.Values.Add("exception", exception);

    if (exception.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
    {
        routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", ((HttpException)exception).GetHttpCode());
    }
    else
    {
        routeData.Values.Add("statusCode", 500);
    }

    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    IController controller = new ErrorPageController();
    controller.Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData));
    Response.End();
}
```

[4]: Add 'Controllers/ErrorPageController.cs'

```
public class ErrorPageController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Error(int statusCode, Exception exception)
    {
         Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
         ViewBag.StatusCode = statusCode + " Error";
         return View();
    }
}
```

[5]: in 'Views/Shared/Error.cshtml'

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
@{
    ViewBag.Title = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.StatusCode)) ? ViewBag.StatusCode : "500 Error";
}

<h1 class="error">@(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.StatusCode) ? ViewBag.StatusCode : "500 Error"):</h1>

//@Model.ActionName
//@Model.ContollerName
//@Model.Exception.Message
//@Model.Exception.StackTrace
```

Comment: Best answer I found for last 20 hours of searching.