# Mixing MVC and Web API Error Handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, error-handling

We have an `MVC 4` web application where we use the `web.config` file to handle custom errors.

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="403" />
        <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/AccessDenied" />
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
        <remove statusCode="500" />
        <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/ApplicationError" />
     </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

All ,of which works as expected.

We are now beginning to implement some new features in this project using `AngularJS` and `Web API`.  In our `Web API` controller actions, we are consistently returning a HttpResponseMessage to indicate success/failure of the call.  For example:

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result);
```

The problem (I think!) we are having is that originally `MVC` error handling is intercepting the `BadRequest` result (as is reasonable) so that the `HttpResponseMessage` result data never gets returned to the calling `AngularJS` method.

What is the best way to handle errors in this mixed (`MVC/Web API`) environment so that the `Web API` `HttpResponseMessages` are not lost?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I have found the best solution, but in the end I removed the httpErrors section from the Web.config and built my own error handler in the Global.asax assisted by the following posts:

- [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29712134/236860)
- [PrideParrot](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/5/exception_handling_in_asp_net_mvc#returningviews)

**Global.asax**

```
public void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var httpContext = ((MvcApplication) sender).Context;
    var currentController = "";
    var currentAction = "";
    var currentRouteData =
        RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));

    if (currentRouteData != null)
    {
        if (
            !String.IsNullOrEmpty(
                currentRouteData.Values["controller"]?.ToString()))
        {
            currentController = currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["action"]?.ToString()))
        {
            currentAction = currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        }
    }

    var ex = Server.GetLastError();
    var httpEx = ex as HttpException;
    var controller = new ErrorController();
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    var statusCode = httpEx?.GetHttpCode() ?? 500;
    string action;

    switch (statusCode)
    {
        case 400:
            action = "BadRequest";
            break;
        case 403:
            action = "AccessDenied";
            break;
        case 404:
            action = "NotFound";
            break;
        default:
            action = "Index";
            break;
    }

    httpContext.ClearError();
    httpContext.Response.Clear();
    httpContext.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;
    httpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

    if (statusCode >= 500)
    {
        Server.Transfer("/Error/ServerError.html");
        return;
    }

    routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
    routeData.Values["action"] = action;
    routeData.Values["statusCode"] = statusCode;

    controller.ViewData.Model = new HandleErrorInfo(ex, currentController,
        currentAction);

    ((IController) controller).Execute(
        new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), routeData));
}
```

My error controller then looked like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
 public sealed class ErrorController
     : AblController
 {
     public ActionResult Index(int statusCode)
     {
         ViewBag.StatusCode = statusCode;
         return View("Error");
     }


     // HTTP 400 - Bad Request
     public ActionResult BadRequest()
     {
         // Now handled by Global.asax - Application_Error
         // Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
         // Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

         if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
         {
             return Json(
                 new
                 {
                     error = new ErrorSummary("Bad Request")
                 });
         }

         return View();
     }


     // HTTP 403 - Access Denied
     public ActionResult AccessDenied()
     {
         // Now handled by Global.asax - Application_Error
         // Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
         // Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

         if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
         {
             return Json(
                 new
                 {
                     error = new ErrorSummary("Access Denied")
                 });
         }

         return View();
     }


     // HTTP 404 - Not Found
     public ActionResult NotFound()
     {
         // Now handled by Global.asax - Application_Error
         // Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
         // Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

         if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
         {
             return Json(
                 new
                 {
                     error = new ErrorSummary("Not Found")
                 });
         }

         return View();
     }
 }
```

}

I also turned the custom error mode off in the Web.config

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

This solution needs ***more testing***, but so far it seems to be performing as expected/as required.