# WebAPI BadRequest Dropping Response Data

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an *ASP.NET WebAPI (v2)* controller action that has the following general structure:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(UserDTO model)
{
    try {
        // do something
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var error = new {
            errorMessage = ex.Message,
            userId = 123,
            // some other simple data
        };
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, error);
    } 

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, model);
}
```

When I run this on my local development server (*IIS Express*) and an error is thrown, I get the expected JSON payload back.

```
{
    config: {...},
    data: {
        errorMessage: "User invalid",
        userId: 123,
        ...
    },
    status: 400,
    statusText: "Bad Request"
}
```

When I run the same code/data on the remote/production server (IIS 8.5), all I get back is:

```
{
    config: {...},
    data: "Bad Request,
    status: 400,
    statusText: "Bad Request"
}
```

The custom `data` payload is lost/stripped away from the response.  This *appears* to be related to the `HttpStatusCode` used in the `Request.CreateResponse()` call as if I change `HttpStatusCode.BadRequest` to `HttpStatusCode.OK` then the custom data payload is downloaded.

As I test, I tried changing the return to `Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);` but the results were the same, i.e. the data was returned as a simple *"Bad Request"* string.

For reference, the API is being called by an AngularJS `$http.post()` call.

Why is the change in `HttpStatusCode` changing the response payload on the production server but not locally?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry about this dumb question but I have to ask - Are you absolutely certain the response in coming from this exception?  IIS and Express have different process stacks so the exception may be from elsewhere.   In IIS, run with Failed Request Trace enabled to help locate the exception point

Comment: If it is dumb, I've just asked myself the same thing :-)  Yes, I think it is, but...  It appears to be related to the error handling used on the production web site.  If I strip out the <httpErrors /> from <system.webServer> then the data is returned correctly.  So, as this is a mixed MVC/WebAPI application then I guess my question should be is how do you avoid invoking the default error handlers for WebAPI calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was down to the following section in Web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="403" />
        <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL"
               path="/Error/AccessDenied" />
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL"
               path="/Error/NotFound" />
        <remove statusCode="500" />
        <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL"
               path="/Error/ApplicationError" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

It was 'odd' because these pages were not being returned by the API call, but with their removal, the API call returned the correct payload - presumably the `HttpStatusCode.BadRequest` was being intercepted by an error handler somewhere hence losing the original response data?

With these handlers I removed, I resorted to using the `Application_Error` handler in *Global.asax* as described [by ubik404 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29712134/236860).

There may well be a better/alternative way to achieve the same result, but this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `existingResponse="Replace"`, I just had the same issue and that solved it for me. The default value is `Auto`.

Your answer lead me to find the real problem, so thanks! :)

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/)